# Removing an element on click

Tags: jquery, onclick

I do not know the exact title of this question.
but I want to ask ..

```
<div id="listInserts">
   <div>tes <a class="del" rel="54" href="#">X</a></div>
</div>
```

I have a jquery script like this

```
$.get('dashboard/xhrGetListings', function(o) {

    for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
    {
        $('#listInserts').append('<p>' + o[i].text + '<a class="del" rel="' + o[i].id + '" href="#">X</a></p>');
    }

    $('#listInserts').on("click",".del",function() {
        delItem = $(this);
        var id = $(this).attr('rel');

        $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'id': id}, function(o) {
            delItem.parent().remove();
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
}, 'json');
```

The above script works only partially for me.  I would like that when an item within collection for selector `.del` is clicked then the available data on `id=listInserts` is removed without reloading page.  The item is being removed just fine, but the page is being reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to prevent page reload, use [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), like

```
$('#listInserts').on("click",".del",function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); //prevents page from being reloaded
  .....
```

Comment: @IrvanKristian If you want to get a pragmatic/better answer, providing  a demo on websites like http://jsfiddle.net can help a lot. By the way, what do you mean by _"available data"_?

Comment: like in this video ..
but in the video using jquery 1.6          http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hh2IXrdT4g&list=PL7A20112CF84B2229&index=4

Answer (score 0):

- your code not reloading with me
- but try to post "on" handler out your get event

  ```
  //get
  $.get('dashboard/xhrGetListings', function(o) {
  for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
   {
    $('#listInserts').append('<p>' + o[i].text + '<a class="del" rel="' + o[i].id + '" href="#">X</a></p>');
   }
   }, 'json');

  //on
  $('#listInserts').on("click",".del",function() {
  delItem = $(this);
  var id = $(this).attr('rel');

  $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'id': id}, function(o) {
      delItem.parent().remove();
  }, 'json');
  return false;
   });
  ```